# Different page labels/numbering in PDF viewer

Tags: hyperref, numbering, page-numbering, arabic, roman

I am using the `report` class and would like to have front matter with a different numbering than the main matter.
So I use Roman numbering at first and then Arabic numbering later on, but what I would like is when viewing the PDF that page 1 corresponds to the actual page 1 (and not I) etc when quickly jumping to a page (and then I would give the page with page number I).

So I tried to include:

```
\usepackage[
    pdfpagelabels,
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}
```

Which in essence works, but it's giving me all kinds of problems, so I was wondering whether it was possible to do this without using `hyperref`?

MWE, this is essentially what I want to achieve, but hopefully without `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[%
    pdfpagelabels,
]{hyperref}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}

Bla bla bla

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{chap2}
bla bla bla 

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For pdfTeX:

```
\documentclass{report}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}

Bla bla bla

\cleardoublepage
% Best place at the start of the Arabic numbered pages
% after \cleardoublepage and before the page number is
% reset in \pagenumbering{arabic}.
\pdfcatalog{%
  /PageLabels<<%
    /Nums[%
      % Page numbers are zero based.
      % Uppercase roman numbers starting with first page.
      0<</S/R>>%
      % Arabic numbers starting with current page.
      \the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax<</S/D>>%
    ]%
  >>%
}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{chap2}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

The syntax for `/PageLabels` is specified in the [PDF specification](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), section "12.4.2 Page Labels".